# Enable keyboard tweaks on apps which run as root

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, jailbreak, tweaks

I am using exKey and KeyShorcut Pro tweaks for customization of my iOS keyboard, on a jailbroken iPhone. I wanted to duplicate my Facebook app and used [duplicatorstore.com](http://duplicatorstore.com/) to duplicate Facebook as it supports iOS 9.0.2. I installed 'Facebook 2' from this site.

When I try to use 'Facebook 2' app, the iOS keyboard is shown like Cydia, iFile (exKey and KeyShorcut Pro features are not shown) and I must write my Facebook password every time I open the duplicate Facebook app. I want to use KeyShorcut Pro tweak with this duplicate Facebook app because I don't want to always write my long Facebook password and want to set it to a key shortcut.

How can enable keyboard tweak features on a iOS app which runs as root?

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible. Cydia Enable tweak already doing this. Just a problem. Not updated for 1.1.26 of Cydia version.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as tweaks run as the mobile user such that they can be controlled by Cydia Substrate. This means that if a tweak malfunctions, Substrate Safe Mode can disable the tweak.

It would be dangerous for a tweak with a large/non-existent filter list (i.e. available in many/all apps including the SpringBoard) to run as root which would prevent it being disabled. If such a tweak were to inject into SpringBoard and cause a crash, *and* not be able to be disabled in the event of the aforementioned crash, the device would need to be restored.